# Produce a precision weighted average among rows with repeated observations

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I have a dataframe similar to the one generated below.  Some individuals have more than one observation for a particular variable and each variable has an associated standard error (SE) for the estimate.  I would like to create a new dataframe that contains only a single row for each individual.  For individuals with more than one observation, such as Kim or Bob, I need to calculate a precision weighted average based on the standard errors of the estimates along with a variance for the newly calculated weighted mean.  For example, for Bob, for var1, this means that I would want his var1 value in the new dataframe to be:

```
weighted.mean(c(example$var1[2], example$var1[10]), 
   c(1/example$SE1[2], 1/example$SE1[10]))
```

and for Bob's new SE1, which would be the variance of the weighted mean, to be:

```
1/sum(1/example$SE1[2] + 1/example$SE1[10])
```

I have tried using the aggregate function and am able to calculate the arithmetic mean of the values, but the simple function I wrote does not use the standard errors nor can it deal with the NAs.

```
aggregate(example[,1:4], by = list(example[,5]), mean)
```

Would appreciate any help in developing some code to work through this problem.  Here is the example dataset.

```
set.seed(1562)
example=data.frame(rnorm(10,8,2))
colnames(example)[1]=("var1")
example$SE1=rnorm(10,2,1)
example$var2=rnorm(10,8,2)
example$SE2=rnorm(10,2,1)
example$id= 
  c ("Kim","Bob","Joe","Sam","Kim","Kim","Joe","Sara","Jeff","Bob")
example$SE1[5]=NA
example$var1[5]=NA
example$SE2[10]=NA
example$var2[10]=NA
example

       var1      SE1      var2        SE2   id
1   9.777769 2.451406  6.363250  2.2739566  Kim
2   8.753078 2.174308  6.219770  1.4978380  Bob
3   7.977356 2.107739  6.835998  2.1647437  Joe
4  11.113048 2.713242 11.091650  1.7018666  Sam
5         NA       NA 11.769884 -0.1310218  Kim
6   5.271308 1.831475  6.818854  3.0294338  Kim
7   7.770062 2.094850  6.387607  0.2272348  Joe
8   9.837612 1.956486  8.517445  3.5126378 Sara
9   4.637518 2.516896  7.173460  2.0292454 Jeff
10  9.004425 1.592312        NA         NA  Bob
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the `plyr` package for these sorts of problems. It should be functionally equivalent to `aggregate`, but I think it is nice and convenient to use. There are lots of examples and a great ~20 page intro to plyr on the [website](http://plyr.had.co.nz/). For this problem, since the data starts as a data.frame and you want another data.frame on the other end, we use `ddply()`

```
library(plyr)
#f1()
ddply(example, "id", summarize, 
      newMean = weighted.mean(x=var1, 1/SE1, na.rm = TRUE),
      newSE = 1/sum(1/SE1, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
```

Which returns:

```
    id newmean   newSE
1  Bob  8.8982 0.91917
2 Jeff  4.6375 2.51690
3  Joe  7.8734 1.05064
4  Kim  7.1984 1.04829
5  Sam 11.1130 2.71324
6 Sara  9.8376 1.95649
```

Also check out `?summarize` and ?`transform` for some other good background. You can also pass an anonymous function to the `plyr` functions if necessary for more complicated tasks.

Or use `data.table` package which can prove faster for some tasks:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(example, key="id")
#f2()
dt[, list(newMean = weighted.mean(var1, 1/SE1, na.rm = TRUE),
          newSE = 1/sum(1/SE1, na.rm = TRUE)),
   by = "id"]
```

A quick benchmark:

```
library(rbenchmark)
#f1 = plyr, #f2 = data.table
benchmark(f1(), f2(), 
          replications = 1000,
          order = "elapsed",
          columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))

      test elapsed relative
    2 f2()   3.580   1.0000
    1 f1()   6.398   1.7872
```

So `data.table()` is ~ 1.8x faster for this dataset on my simple laptop.